# How to make a filtered list from pillar in saltstack

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I have some pillar data with hostnames

```
my_hosts:
  a.example.com:
    include_me: true
  b.example.com:
    include_me: false
  c.example.com:
    include_me: true
  d.example.com:
    include_me: false
```

and I want to construct a list of those hostnames filtered by a variable condition (here, to be simple, `include_me`).  So the output should be a variable something like

```
{% set interesting_hosts = ??? %}   # == [a.example.com, c.example.com]
```

so that I can have some rule

```
{% for a_host in in interesting_hosts %}
/var/cool/stuff]{{ a_host }}:
  file.managed:
    ... something cool ...
{% endfor %}
```

But is there a way to create this filtered list (the `???`)?

Comment: Is it important to you that the `interesting_hosts` variable be the final filtered result? I find the filters and tests difficult to figure out in Jinja2 personally. It might be simpler if you just used an `if` statement inside of your `for` loop and only included hosts with specific attributes. Would that suffice?

Comment: @Mike Thanks, that's probably better than the hacked solution I've got, although I'd have preferred to find something more readable.

Comment: Yep, I totally understand.

Comment: So I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this with a Python Saltstack `render` - https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/all/salt.renderers.py.html. And now that I think of it, I'm pretty sure I've done something like this before. I'll see if I can dig it up later today.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is such option.

Did you read [jinja filters](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html) manual?

Jinja *kind of* supports list map/filter-like operations

Make sure your jinja2 is at least 2.9 version (`pip install --upgrade Jinja2`)

As dict filtering is tedious and won't be readable, if you could format your pillar to be a list of dicts, like this:

```
  my_hosts:
    - host: a.example.com
      include_me: True
    - host: b.example.com
      include_me: False
    - host: c.example.com
      include_me: True
    - host: d.example.com
      include_me: False
```

then setting interesting hosts is as simple as:

```
{% set my_hosts = salt['pillar.get']("my_hosts") %}
{% set interesting_hosts = my_hosts|selectattr("include_me", "equalto", True)|map(attribute="host")|list %}
```

Comment: can you tell me pls where exactly we set my_hosts ? in the pillars or states ?

Comment: `my_hosts` is in the pillar

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your hosts in list something like below example:

```
{% load_yaml as interesting_hosts %}
  - a.example.com
  - b.example.com
  - c.example.com
  - d.example.com
{% endload %}

{% load_yaml as not_interesting_hosts %}
  - e.example.com
{% endload %}
```